# Using transition mouseout in css3

Tags: html, css, menu

I've been using transition to make simple menu "underline" (its actually `border-bottom`) transition, when it hover you will get `border-bottom` in action and you will see him pop out.
However, there is a problem with transition "mouseout" effect, when I get my mouse off from  `li > a:hover` it disappeares without any effect.

**CSS3 Code:**

```
/*Menu*/
#menu{
    float: right;
    margin: -60px 0px 0;
}

#menu ul{
    list-style-type:none;
}

#menu ul li{
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

#menu ul li a{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #a1a1a1;
    font-size: 19px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}
#menu li > a:hover {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

**Q:** How can I get mouseout transition effect in css3?

http://jsfiddle.net/B6ceP/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the transition in the initial state, not just on `:hover`. Also, if you want to animate back to no border, you need a border there, just make it transparent (or 0px wide):

```
#menu ul li a{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #a1a1a1;
    font-size: 19px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/B6ceP/1/)